# Real I/O Inconsistency

Tags: io, floating-point, fortran

Here is my program:

```
program ch0501
implicit none
real :: btan
read(*,'(F20.8)'),btan
PRINT '(F20.8)', btan
end program ch0501
```

When run, I input `123.12345678` on the keyboard.
However, I get

```
        123.12345886
```

as output on the screen.

Why is that? I tried compiling on different machines using `gfortran` and get the same result.

Comment: The closest 32 bit IEEE binary floating point number to 123.12345678 is 123.1234588623046875.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the link! Yes, you're right - according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format the REAL type is binary32 and the cause for the inconsistency. I also got the number you got after doing a lot of arithmetic by hand  - out of curiosity, how did you find the closest floating point so quickly? I imagine this will be helpful in helping me to spot rounding errors quickly.

Comment: Java has a data type, BigDecimal, that can represent exactly any terminating decimal fraction, and print it exactly. Any floating point number can be converted exactly to BigDecimal: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(123.12345678F));`. The "F" makes the literal 32 bit, not 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks! I just did a Google search and found this: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html